# Unix shell - Find unique columns by comparing two files

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk

I have two files where I want to compare the first column to find the unique ones using unix shell.

File 1:

```
yellow
green
red
white
```

File 2:

```
yellow,not_started
red,in_progress
```

I want the output to be

```
green
white
```

Comment: Could you please do add your efforts which you have put in order to solve your own problems in your post and let us know then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy to do with [`join`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/join.1.html):

```
$ join -t, -v1 <(sort file1.txt) <(sort file2.txt)
green
white
```

`-v1` tells it to print out records in the first file that don't match up to a record in the second file. The sorts are because `join` requires its input files to be sorted based on the (default first) join column.

Alternative using `awk`:

```
$ awk -F, 'NR == FNR { seen[$1] = 1; next } !($0 in seen)' file2.txt file1.txt
green
white
```

Note the second file comes first in the arguments to `awk`.